# When writing data into qRAM, can I do it in a superposition state?

Tags: quantum-gate, superposition, quantum-memory

In general, quantum algorithms are said to be hybrid algorithms.

Especially when storing data in qRAM, it seems to be done through classical calculations.

Is it possible to write this part directly to qRAM after passing through Hadamard Gate and performing a specific operation?

In other words, can the data in the superposition states be stored directly in qRAM?

Comment: This is what qRAM is designed for, to store quantum states. In some algorithms you need qRAM to reach their "full" speed as these algorithms expect that they are feeded with quatunm data, i.e. from qRAM.

Comment: @MartinVesely Do you mean that storing data in qRAM can be done in the classic way (one memory address at a time) and also in superposition states (multiple memory addresses at a time)?

Comment: As far as I know each memory cell can contain a qubit in superposition and it is also possible to address multiple cells simultaneously. See this article https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.1879